# JavaScript positional property access in Objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "dealerListItemDToes": [
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Property called '`dealerListItemDToes`' will always be at the given position in the object but its name can vary depending on the HTTP requests.

How can I access the property '`dealerListItemDToes`' and retrieve its content without referencing its name?

Comment: Or in other words. You want the one and only property (or its content) from `_embedded` regardless of its name.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's the only property of the `_embedded` object, you could access the `[0]`th item in an array of object entries:

```js
const obj = {
  "_embedded": {
    "dealerListItemDToes": [
      {
        // ...
      },
      {
        // ...
      }
    ]
  }
};

console.log(
  Object.entries(obj._embedded)[0]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```js
let data = {
  "_embedded": {
    "dealerListItemDToes": [{
      "h": 1
    }]
  }
}

console.log(data._embedded[Object.keys(data._embedded)[0]])
```